# Changing a user password in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, passwords, password-recovery

What is the best way to change a user password (in a table) in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (see image example)?

I know you can run a query, but I am not sure how to. Also, can you actually create an MD5hash generated password and paste/enter it into the password field?

[image]

Comment: Possible candidate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: What type of application created those? Is it custom app you written or purchased product?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a user is unique, just search for that username in a `WHERE` clause.  You can use the [HashBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function to generate the MD5 hash:

`SELECT HashBytes('MD5', 'stringToHashGoesHere')`

You can then insert that into the MD5 column

Comment: The HashBytes method does not seem to be working. It fills the field with the following value: 쀙輦莛跉钬짿㣑. Also, using my text password that was hashed, does not validate...(because of the chinese...the string is suppose to look something like: d131dd02c5e6eec4 693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab58712467eab 4004583eb8fb7f89

Comment: What is your column type on the database?  If it is nvarchar, then you get "Chinese like" characters because you are inserting a varbinary value returned by HASHBYTES into an nvarchar column, so SQL Server is trying to interpret the bytes as Unicode code points (characters).  

In order to be able to insert the returned value into your table, you need to either 1)do a `CONVERT` on the returned result or 2) change your column type to varbinary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update password field of specific userid. It is hard to see your actual table and column names so I just substituted with generic names. Please note that HASHBYTES will return `VARBINARY` value.

```
DECLARE @MyPassword VARBINARY(250) = HASHBYTES('MD5','MyNewPassword')
UPDATE MyTable
SET PasswordField = @MyPassword
Where UserId = 'MyUser'
```

Comment: Thank you. I have done that, but it does not work. The updated value in the table looks as follows: 쀙輦莛跉钬짿㣑. Is using MD5 the correct way then? Isn't there another type of encryption method to use then?

Comment: It is possible that it is being stored as `VARCHAR` type instead of `VARBINARY`, in that case try to use online site like http://www.md5hashgenerator.com/index.php and then update password field with output